# On global section of bundles on hypersurfaces in projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X = Z(f) $ be a degree $d$ irreducible hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n$. Let's consider $(X ,\mathcal O_X)$  as a closed subscheme of $(\mathbb P^n , \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n})$ .Then we have for any fixed natural number $r$ the following restriction map $ f : H^0(\mathbb P^n , \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(r)) \to H^0(X ,\mathcal O_X(r))$ given by $s \to s|_X$, where $s$ is a degree $r$ homogeneous polynomial in $n+1$ variables.

At this point my questions are  : $(1)$ Is it correct to interpret 
$s|_X$ algebraically as  $ s +(f) \in (\mathbb K[x_0,....,x_n]/(f))_r = H^0(X ,\mathcal O_X(r))$ ?

$(2)$ $s|_X$ vanishing at a point $x \in X$ is same as vanishing of $s$ at the same point $x$ considered as a point in $\mathbb P^n$(Please correct me if I am wrong). How does this idea of vanishing at a point translates in the previous algebraic interpretation?

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: (1) is correct provided you interpret $s + (f)$ correctly as a homogeneous ideal, so it consists of all expressions $s + gf$ with $g$ homogeneous of degree $r - d$. For (2), recall that $s(x) = 0$ is the same as saying $s \in I_x$. If $x \in X$, that means that the $gf$ term in my discussion of (1) lies in $I_X \subset I_x$, so vanishing at $x$ still boils down to the original polynomial $s$ lying in $I_x$.

Comment: @TabesBridges, If I understand you correctly ,then are you try to convey the following: $s|_X$ vanishes at $x \in X $ means  all expressions $s+gf$ has to be in $I_x$.Now since $gf \in I_X \subset I_x$,this forces $s \in I_x$i.e $s$ vanishes at $x$.And the converse is also along the same line?